# Calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2+k(k-1)}$

Tags: calculus

This is a homework question and I don't know how to solve it since it doesn't go to infinity but just simply calculating. Is anyone know how to do?
$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2+k(k-1)}$

Comment: Are you being asked for closed form for the finite sum or its limit as $n \to \infty$?  The limit has a simple closed form and can be found using calculus.

Comment: The closed form isnt elementary, i think it revolves around these two $\psi(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+z}$ and the fact that $n^2+k^2-k=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4n^2}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4n^2}}{2}\right)$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Write
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2+k(k-1)}=n \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(k-a)(k-b)}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the quadratic equation in $k$
$$k^2-k+n^2=0$$ that is to say
$$(a,b)=\frac{1}{2} \left(1\pm\sqrt{1-4 n^2}\right)$$ which are complex numbers.

Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1}{(k-a)(k-b)}=\frac 1 {a-b}\left(\frac{1}{k-a}-\frac{1}{k-b}\right)$$ and think about generalized harmonic numbers or polygamma functions.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k-c}=H_{n-c}-H_{-c}=\psi (n+1-c)-\psi (1-c)$$ Now, consider that $n$ is large and use series expansion to find that
$$S_n=C+\frac{8+3 \pi }{96 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ where, as @Henry wrote in comments, the limit $C$ *"has a simple closed form and can be found using calculus"*.

Answer (score 1):

Calculus II. Rieamann sums and definite integral.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k(k-1)}\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\color{red}{(1-0)}}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(\tfrac 
 kn)^2-\frac1n(\tfrac kn)+1}\\
=\lim_{n,m\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(\tfrac 
 kn)^2-\frac1m(\tfrac kn)+1}\\
=\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2-\frac1m x+1}dx\\
=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\frac\pi 4.$$